# Python Code to get data at set time intervals

Tags: python

I am curious if anyone knows how to get from http://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/flyfaaindex.jsp?ARPT=SFO&p=0 
 to get a result like this:
http://cdn.abclocal.go.com/three/kgo/weather/links/SFO_DELAYS.txt
The result I originally worked well but than an actual delay occured and gave me this:

```
2016/7/11 23:35Z<b>30 minutes</b> in length and increasing. ,<b>General        Arrival Delays: </b> Arrival traffic is experiencing airborne delays of 15 minutes or less. ,<strong>KJFK 112251Z 17009KT 10SM FEW055 SCT180 BKN260 23/16 A3008 RMK AO2 SLP186 T02280161</strong>
```

Part of the message got cut off. Also, I am curious if there is a way to get rid of the bolding as well as the strong.

Here is my actual code:
   # The following modules read the data online and import it into a spreadsheet      called "MetResearch"
   import numpy as N
   import urllib2
   from lxml import html
   from lxml.etree import tostring
   import time

while True:

## GETTING THE METAR CODE

## Reads the entire page as a string

```
tree = html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen('http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/index?station_ids=kjfk&std_trans=translated&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&chk_tafs=on&submit=Submit').read())
```

## Then selecting the first pre element, which has the METAR info

```
td_text = tostring(tree.xpath('//strong')[1])
```

## Then prints the METAR info (not necessary here)

```
#print td_text[:]
tree1 = html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/flyfaaindex.jsp?ARPT=JFK').read())
month= str(time.gmtime()[1])
day= str(time.gmtime()[2])
year= str(time.gmtime()[0])
hour= time.gmtime()[3]
minute= time.gmtime()[4]
td_text1 = tostring(tree1.xpath('//b')[-3])
td_text2 = tostring(tree1.xpath('//b')[-2])
f1=open('/home/jkalb/public_html/JFK.txt','a')
f1.write(month+"/"+day+"/"+year+" "+str(hour)+":"+str(minute)+"Z")
f1.write(td_text1+","+td_text2+","+td_text)
f1.close()


time.sleep(300)
```

I am also having trouble keeping the program up and running once I close the Canopy/VI window.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I am having problems writing my code and need a good example of a unix command/code other than wget to get online data since I tried wget on the first link but it did not come out right.

Comment: To me it is indeed also not very clear what the actual problem is. Python has excellent support for xml.

Comment: I am trying to find a way using Python to get from the faa link to something like the cdn link but the code I am getting does not work. @Roland

Comment: Do I spot an erroneous double quote in the wget command? And this is only pseudo code? Why not your actual command?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to want to download the stuff from faa.gov as html, you might want to do this:

```
wget -O x.html http://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/flyfaaindex.jsp?ARPT=SFO&p=0
```

in order to process the x.html file with your python script to get some SFO_DELAYS.txt output file.

With your edited question the problem is now how to repeat this every 5 minutes. Either use `cron`, which is a standard unix (linux) utility, with lots of info on the internet, esp in unix tutorials, e.g. [here](https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html). Example:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
 0,5,10      *          *             *                *            /home/roland/wget.rc
```

where wget.rc is a small shell script with the wget command. (I would not try to put a complex shell command with redirection etc in the cron tab.) You can expand the 0,5,10 up to ... ,50,55.

Or make a script with an endless loop, e.g. in python, or shell, save this in a file like get.rc:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
  wget ...
  sleep 300
done
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x get.rc
```

Run the file:

```
./get.rc
```

Comment: To sum up this and the other response. I was limited to two links so I had to do the same fly faa link. But I want it to get data every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Why not edit your question saying "from some faa.gov link" and put the exact url in the wget command? If my answer is not what you expect, your problem still needs more explanation.

Comment: I just edited it right now.  Although the actual code on my Linux/Unix is a different airport.

Comment: Would you think   wget */5 * * * * wget http://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/flyfaaindex.jsp?ARPT=JFK >> JFK.txt do the trick?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use cron syntax in the wget command. Please see my updated answer with a cron example.